# Failing to import an export class using angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

So I've been trying to follow the tutorial by [egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-writing-a-simple-angular-2-component). However I can't seem to get the step2 to work.

I've created the TodoInput class like this:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';
@Component({
    selector: 'todo-input'
})

@View({
    template: `
        <div>This is written in the todoInput export class</div>
    `   
})

export class TodoInput{}
```

And using it in the helloWorld.ts like this:

```
import{Component,View,bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import{TodoInput} from './TodoInput';

@Component({
    selector: 'hello-world'
})

@View({
    directives: [TodoInput],
    template: `
        <div>
            <h1>This is a heading!</h1>
            <todo-input/>
        </div>
    `
})

class HelloWorld{}

bootstrap(HelloWorld);
```

and finally using the hello-world tag in the index.html like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular 2 Quickstart</title>
        <script src="node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <hello-world></hello-world>
        <script>
            System.import('src/helloWorld.js');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I try to run this I get an error: **"GET /src/TodoInput" Error (404): "Not found"**. What am I doing wrong?

I am running on this version of angular2:

```
"angular2/angular2.d.ts": {
  "commit": "78d36dd49b6b55b9fdfe61776a12bf05c8b07777"
}
```

Comment: are you sure `TodoInput` is in `src` and not in a subdirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this working example

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/lLGlxlXXRVEDtu7QA112?p=info)

You need to have .ts file extension for helloWorld file.

```
System.import("src/helloWorld").catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

Rest is fine. Look at link given above.

Comment: Thanks! This lead me to the solution. Turns out I needed to change the order of some statements in the index.html file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the order in which the statements in the index.html file was written. The following was my solution:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular 2 Quickstart</title>
        <script src="node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <hello-world></hello-world>
        <script>
            System.config({defaultJSExtensions:true});    
        </script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            System.import('src/helloWorld').catch(console.error.bind(console));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also added the `System.config({defaultJSExtensions:true})` to make the `src/helloWorld` (with no extension) work.